# Older scifi book about a woman who lives on a barge on a colonized water world. Gets involved in political intrigue when she meets a man

Tags: story-identification, books, space-colonization

The setting was a largely water world colonized by humans.  Since colonization it has been isolated and experienced technological regression.   The protagonist is a young woman who works on her own, and lives aboard barge/skiff, transporting goods.  Eventually, she finds and helps a man who's involved in high level political scheming/intrigue trying to free the world from it's isolation and "dark ages."

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 5):

This could be [Angel with the Sword](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2426) by [C J Cherryh](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?16) - the first novel of the [Merovingen Nights](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?1128) series - published in 1985. [Fantastic Fiction's plot summary](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/c/c-j-cherryh/angel-with-sword.htm) matches many of the details that you mention:

> In Merovingen, a watery canal-laced city, much like Earth's Venice, society is segregated along class lines between the lower and upper cities. Against her better judgment, Altair Jones, 17, rescues an unconscious man from a canal near her poleboat. She is fascinated by Mondragon's good looks and elegant ways and begins to fall in love with him. Even though she knows there is no future for a water rat like herself with such a man, she decides to watch over him and rescue him from his enemies; enemies who turn out to be the most powerful people in the upper city.